# How to update date_modified with sysdate after updating another row?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am updating an Oracle table from another table, I then need to update the date_modified field with sysdate for all those rows that have been updated. My code currently looks like this:

```
UPDATE
table1 t1
SET
field1 = (SELECT t2.value
          FROM table2 t2
          WHERE t1.r_id = t2.r_id
          AND t2.other in (2,3,4))
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM table2 t2
WHERE t1.r_id = t2.r_id
AND t2.value IS NOT NULL);
```

How do I add the command to update date_modified to sysdate? I have tried a second update command but this is updating the entire table. When I try to add clauses such as:

```
set
date_modified = sysdate (WHERE t2.value IS NOT NULL
                         AND t2.other in (2,3,4))
```

This cannot seem to reference t2 and writing in the full table name doesn't work either.

Is this possible in SQL? I know that I cannot use JOIN in an update statement and Im not sure if there are other rules that are preventing me from doing this.

thanks

Comment: I would suggest using a trigger for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update table1 t1
set
   field1 = (...)
,  date_modified = sysdate   --  << ADD
where exists...
```

Comment: My vote put your reputation over 5000.  You owe me a beer.

Comment: @DanBracuk  lol - beer granted, it could be even more if I gave a damn about reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this does what you want:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET field1 = (SELECT t2.value
              FROM table2 t2
              WHERE t1.r_id = t2.r_id AND t2.other in (2,3,4)
             ),
    data_modified = sysdate
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT t2.value
                  FROM table2 t2
                  WHERE t1.r_id = t2.r_id AND t2.value IS NOT NULL AND
                        t1.field1 = t2.value
                );
```

Note the subtle change to the `WHERE` clause.  This makes sure that the new value is different from the old value.

Answer (score 0):

Hi
 Very nice question. Here you can use Case statement,

```
UPDATE table1 t1 set field1 =  (SELECT t2.value
      FROM table2 t2
      WHERE t1.r_id = t2.r_id
      AND t2.other in (2,3,4))
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM table2 t2
WHERE t1.r_id = t2.r_id
AND t2.value IS NOT NULL),
date_modified = case when t2.value IS NOT NULL
                     AND t2.other in (2,3,4) then sysdate
```

Hope you go it. Else let me know will help you.